# Determine Primary and Foreign Key for two tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-theory

I have 2 tables, that is

**Patient Treatment**

| Datetime | Doctor | Patient | Complaint | Description | Medicine | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/22 17:05 | Name A | Patient K | X | X | X | X |
| 1/1/22 17:11 | Name C | Patient L | X | X | X | X |
| 1/1/22 17:27 | Name B | Patient M | X | X | X | X |
| 1/1/22 17:41 | Name A | Patient N | X | X | X | X |
| 2/1/22 08:38 | Name A | Patient K | X | X | X | X |

**Doctor Personal Data**

| Doctor | Specialist | Join Date | Degree | Hour Work | Phone Number | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name A | X | X | X | X | X | X |
| Name B | X | X | X | X | X | X |
| Name C | X | X | X | X | X | X |
| Name D | X | X | X | X | X | X |

I want to create a relation for both tables. The doctor's name in the Patient Treatment table refers to the doctor's name in Doctor Personal Data to retrieve the doctor's personal data. The Doctor Personal Data table has a unique column (name of doctor). However, I read in several questions on this stackexhange that the primary key being a string is not a good way to go because it's too slow. The two tables don't have an ID number like in most SQL tutorials. What is the best way to determine the primary key and foreign key for both tables?

This is my DDL query

```
CREATE TABLE `patient_treatment` (
      `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `Doctor` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `Patient` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `Complaint` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `Description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `Medicine` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `Address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ) 

CREATE TABLE `doctor_personal_data` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Doctor` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Specialist` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Join Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Degree` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Hour Work` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone Number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

Comment: Please share your query so far.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "*The two tables don't have an ID number*" - Your DDL shows that they both do have `ID` number fields.

Comment: @J.D. i mean no ID number field for raw data

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by raw data, is that a 3rd table of which you didn't provide DDL for? In any case, just add the `ID` field from one table to the other table to be your foreign key, like Niyaz's answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FOREIGN KEY` instead of the name (Doctor). Follow the steps to change your tables:(Backup your database before starting)

Step1: Add the `FOREIGN KEY` column and connect with the `Primary Key`

```
ALTER TABLE `patient_treatment` ADD doctor_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE `patient_treatment` ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES `doctor_personal_data`(id);
```

Step 2: Update new column `doctor_id` in `patient_treatment` table:

```
UPDATE `patient_treatment` 
SET `patient_treatment`.`doctor_id` = (
    SELECT 
        `doctor_personal_data`.`id`
    FROM 
        `doctor_personal_data`
    WHERE 
        `doctor_personal_data`.`Doctor` = `patient_treatment`.`Doctor`
);
```

Step 3: delete the `Doctor` column. (You should be careful about this step, only run this query if the previous steps are successfully implemented)

```
ALTER TABLE `patient_treatment` DROP COLUMN `Doctor`;
```

Now you can join them easily like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM `patient_treatment`
INNER JOIN `doctor_personal_data`
ON `patient_treatment`.`doctor_id` = `doctor_personal_data`.`id`;
```

Comment: If i update data for table patient_treatment, i must do step 2 again? is there a way to be more efficient when the data is very large?

Comment: Based on my understanding of your question, It is a one-time process. Afterward, you add data to the `doctor_id` column instead of the `Doctor` column. I think it takes a couple of minutes to run those queries. If your sample is more than 1M, then adding a temporary `index` for the `Doctor` column may be helpful. After the update, you can delete the `index`.

Answer (score 0):

> has a unique column (name of doctor)

No.  It is really possible that two doctors can have the same name.  It should be an `INDEX`, but not `UNIQUE`.  It is even more likely that two patients can have the same name.

Hence, the table `doctor_personal_data` needs a surrogate `id` as you have done.

`patient_treatment` should use `doctor_id`, not the doctor's name.  Ditto for `patient_id`.  These become `FOREIGN KEYs` to `doctor_personal_data.id` and `patient_data.id`.

You list `medicine`, but there are likely to be many medicines in a single "treatment".  This implies that you might need a table that talks about one treatment for one person, with a many-to-many mapping from that table to an other `medicines` table.

Oh, and you probably *need* to say *which* of *several* doctors prescribed that medicine.

Summarizing:  You have these "Entities", each with an `id`:

```
Patients
Doctors
Ailments (one patient being treated for one injury/disease)
Medicines
```

And then lots of relationships.  There are two important type of SQL relationships:

- 1-to-many -- an id in one table pointing to the other (no extra table)
- many-to-many -- needs an extra table with 2 ids

Once you have that mapped out 'correctly', the FKs are rather obvious.